# Does NeDB use the disk to do find queries?

Tags: node.js, sqlite, nedb

Does NeDB use the disk to do find queries?

Or are find queries 100% using RAM based data structures.

I need to do intensive work using find queries and I don't want to put work on my hard disk.

(As a bonus track, do SQLite find queries also work 100% in memory?)

Answer (score 0):

Depends, if you create indexes on fields, those fields will be held in memory for faster lookup and access. Unindexed field lookups will be hitting disk. This is true for SQLite, as well as most other persistent databases (e.g PostgreSQL, MySQL, MongoDB, and many more)

NeDB is an in-memory database, which means that all data will be held in memory (similar to Redis). That being said, you still have to index fields for faster lookup.

If you want to create indexes on fields in NeDB, they have documentation for that [here](https://github.com/louischatriot/nedb#indexing).

For NeDB, the `_id` field is *automatically indexed*, so you don't have to create an index for that field and querying for `_id` will be substantially faster than querying for another unindexed field.

Comment: If it's held in memory why is it necessary to create indexes if I want to find documents using a certain field? It sounds kinda unnecessary to use the disk there

Comment: Also I tried deleting the database file.db (once it has loaded into memory), and then performing several find operations, and they all worked, even if the file was no longer there. So it doesn't seem that find queries require accessing disk, or am I wrong?

Comment: Indexes for NeDB are kept in an efficient to search data structure known as a Binary Search Tree. At startup, NeDB will load the entire `file.db` into memory, which is why you can still work with the data even if you delete `file.db`.

Comment: Ah okay thanks. My question was if `find` queries need to read the data from disk. Not whether indexes were more efficient or not.

Comment: I've already answered that. *NeDB is an in-memory database*. It only persist data to disk so that you don't lose it if the process crashes or restarts. That's why it loads the entire `file.db` into memory at startup, and operates purely on the in-memory data structures from then on. SQLite however only keeps indexes in memory, while the rest of the columns for that row is kept on disk. So if you query for a field that *isn't indexed*, it will hit the disk.